# Problem with signing smart contract transaction tnvolving ecrecover, keccak256, abi.encodePacked

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, web3py

I'm trying to call the following method on a local smart contract (running on ganache), which is a copy of the Rarible smart contract, [0xd07dc4262BCDbf85190C01c996b4C06a461d2430](https://etherscan.io/address/0xd07dc4262BCDbf85190C01c996b4C06a461d2430#code) and am having some problems with the hashing.

```
function mint(uint256 id, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s, Fee[] memory fees, uint256 supply, string memory uri) public {
        require(isSigner(ecrecover(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(this, id)), v, r, s)), "signer should sign tokenId");
        _mint(id, fees, supply, uri);
    }
```

Relevant python code:

```
from eth_account.messages import encode_intended_validator

def to_32byte_hex(val):
    return w3.toHex(Web3.toBytes(val).rjust(32, b'\0'))

local_contract_address = "0x5a965a6aC0769ca1077b4a3C902709c4b50ea302"
item_number = 777777777

message = encode_intended_validator(w3.toChecksumAddress(local_contract_address), item_number)
signed_msg = w3.eth.account.sign_message(message,private_key=privateKey)
msg = signed_msg.messageHash
v = signed_msg['v']
r = to_32byte_hex(signed_msg['r'])
s = to_32byte_hex(signed_msg['s'])

options = {'gas':50000}
mint = contract.get_function_by_name('mint')
transaction = mint(777777777,v,r,s,[],10,'a').buildTransaction(options)

etc...
```

Output:

With the hacky `to_32byte_hex` function, the arguments are valid, but I'm definitely not getting past the `ecrecover` step in the `mint` function.

I'm not sure how to fix this. I've tried hashing the contract address and item_number together, then signing. I'm assuming v, r, s are ouputs of the message signing process, and that the message being signed is a hash of the concatenation of `local_contract_address` and `item_number`.

If the answer isn't obvious, any resources you'd recommend?

```
ValueError: {'message': 'VM Exception while processing transaction: revert signer should sign tokenId'
```

Comment: Can you please check this? 1) Does the `ecrecover()` return expected address or `0x0` (should be the address) ? 2) If expected address, what does is return for `isSigner()` (should be true)? ... I'm not that familiar with Python, but from what I know about Solidity, one of these is probably going to have an unexpected output and fixing the cause of it (by either sending correct params to `ecrecover` or adding the address to the `signers` variable) will fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found the other way to pass this problem by using 'ethereumjs-util'

```js
const util = require('ethereumjs-util');
// ...

const hash = web3.utils.soliditySha3(
  '0xE5df7fD6756bb8ffD1Cb95e8e3E7f81D9a3b56A2', // contract address
  TOKEN_ID
);
const privateKey = Buffer.from(SIGNER_PRIVATE_KEY, 'hex');
const signature = util.ecsign(util.toBuffer(hash), privateKey);
const v = signature.v;
const r = util.bufferToHex(signature.r);
const s = util.bufferToHex(signature.s);

await raribleToken.mint(
  TOKEN_ID,
  v,
  r,
  s,
  [{ recipient: user1, value: ROYALTY }],
  SUPPLY,
  URI,
  {
    from: user1,
  }
);
```